# SignalR unable to send

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

It seems that I can successfully connect to my server with the reconnecting, reconnected and disconnected events firing properly client side as follows:

```
$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() { tryingToReconnect = true; NotifyReconnect(); });
$.connection.hub.reconnected(function() { tryingToReconnect = false; });
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() { if(tryingToReconnect) { NotifyReconnect(); } });
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
console.log(chat.state);
console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + chat.id);
Success=true;
chat.server.send("Test");
}).fail(function(){ alert("Failed to connect."); });
```

I get the following messages

```
Object {}
Now connected, connection ID=undefined
```

For the send I get

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
```

Which is rather weird because it seems that the connection is established and I get the following messages in the console:

```
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 8c5d12f8-a0a5-
4bbe-a36c-14e74ddfccbf is New.
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(8c5d12f8-a0a5-4bbe-
a36c-14e74ddfccbf)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(8c5d12f8-a0a5-4bbe-
a36c-14e74ddfccbf)
...
```

Although neither Server to Client nor Client to Server sends work, also the OnConnected/OnDisconnected events never fire client side (although they do client side) what is causing this issue?

Comment: ConnectionID exists in the `$.connection.HUBNAME.connection.id` property.    Not `hub.id`.     `chat.state` is going to be an empty array -- think of that like your ASP Session state.  You populate it with what you want.   If you don't add anything, nothing will be there.

The best way I've seen to discover all of SignalR's properties/methods is to breakpoint javascript inside Chrome, and then do the hover-over just like VS.

Comment: are you creating the `chat` object? `var chat = $.connection.chatHub;`

Comment: @Jason connection is still undefined, Jonesy yes